# Nginx Unicorn Rails - 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

I am using the `Ruby on Rails One-Click Application on DigitalOcean` After setting up everything i am getting the following error

```
    2016/06/10 07:48:28 [error] 1702#0: *6 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 106.51.23.165, server: 107.170.3.237, request
: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock/", host: "107.170.3.237"
2016/06/10 07:49:45 [error] 1702#0: *6 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 106.51.23.165, server: 107.170.3.237, request
: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock/", host: "107.170.3.237"
2016/06/10 07:54:14 [error] 2954#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.171.105.237, server: 107.170.3.237, reque
st: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock/", host: "107.170.3.237"
2016/06/10 07:58:54 [error] 3278#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.171.105.237, server: 107.170.3.237, reque
st: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock/", host: "107.170.3.237"
```

**/etc/unicorn.conf**

```
listen "unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock"
#listen "/tmp/unicorn.sock"
worker_processes 4
user "rails"
working_directory "/home/rails/skreem-ror"
pid "/var/run/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
```

**/etc/default/unicorn**

```
# Change paramentres below to appropriate values and set CONFIGURED to yes.
CONFIGURED=yes

# Default timeout until child process is killed during server upgrade,
# it has *no* relation to option "timeout" in server's config.rb.
TIMEOUT=60

# Path to your web application, sh'ld be also set in server's config.rb,
# option "working_directory". Rack's config.ru is located here.
APP_ROOT=/home/rails/skreem-ror

# Server's config.rb, it's not a rack's config.ru
CONFIG_RB=/etc/unicorn.conf

# Where to store PID, sh'ld be also set in server's config.rb, option "pid".
PID=/var/run/unicorn.pid
RAILS_ENV="development"
UNICORN_OPTS="-D -c $CONFIG_RB -E $RAILS_ENV"

PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global
DAEMON=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/unicorn
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rails**

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    root /home/rails/skreem-ror/public;
    server_name 107.170.3.237 skreem.in www.skreem.in admin.skreem.in brands.skreem.in api.skreem.in;
    index index.htm index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
                    try_files $uri @app;
            }

     location @app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `listen "/var/run/unicorn.sock"` in your `unicorn.conf`?

Comment: @mrwillihog yes been trying to figure where the bledy sock file is :(

Comment: @mrwillihog there us only a `.pid` file there in that path :(

Comment: @mrwillihog the file is there. but its empty. is that the issue? when i do `nano` nothing is in that file

Comment: No, i think it should be empty (im no expert here). I just noticed you had `unix:` in your config file but the unicorn documentation doesnt say you need that.

Comment: @mrwillihog i have removed it tried as well. :(

Comment: And you removed it from your nginx config too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114342/discussion-between-harsha-m-v-and-mrwillihog).

Comment: Your unicorn server isn't running. Have you tried `service unicorn start`?

Comment: @tombeynon yes sir. have tried that by doing the following `service unicorn restart` is there any way to verify if its running?

Comment: try `ps aux | grep unicorn`. I expect it's not running.

Comment: If it's not, is there anything in `/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log` that might indicate the issue?

Comment: @tombeynon interesting that is running and when i tail the unicorn.log i am getting the following error continuously  http://pastebin.com/L5QTdhUN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to add `gem unicorn` to your Gemfile and run bundle install.